# Do I need one htaccess file in every folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have mutliple files/folders in a structure like this:

2019/
2018/
...
2000/Summer/
2000/Winter/
index.php
.htaccess

If the user enter domain.com/2019/ he should be redirected to index.php in main root. Same if the user enter domain.com/2018/...

My question is:
Do I need one htaccess in each of this folders to make it happend?, or could I add something to the main .htaccess that automatically add this behavior to each and every folder on my domain that don't have a index.php file?

Comment: Actually you should try not to use _any_ such dynamic configuration files at all. Those files have a lot of disadvantages over implementing redirection rules in the real configuration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply want to add these line in your .htaccess file

```
# Turn rewriting on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect requests to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.png$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.jpg$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.css$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.gif$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.js$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /index.php
```